# batch file not terminating prematurely when running pyenv shell

Tags: batch-file, cmd, pyenv

I wrote a script to use for initialising new projects' folders. The code is as follows:

```bash
@echo off

REM Requires 1-2 arguments
REM %1 = Project name. Must be valid folder name. Required.
REM %2 = Python version to use in 3.xx.xx format, for setting up local pyenv environment. Optional. Uses global Python version if missing.

if [%1] == [] (
    echo Project name undefined.
    echo Please run %~nx0 project-name
    exit /B 1
)

if [%2] NEQ [] (
    pyenv shell %2
)

if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools poetry

    cd ..
    poetry new --src %1

    robocopy .\new_project_template\to_copy\ .\%1\ /E /ZB /COPYALL /W:5

    cd %1
    if [%2] NEQ [] (
        pyenv local %2
    )
    poetry config virtualenvs.in-project true
    poetry add black isort flake8 pytest pytest-cov pre-commit toml --group dev
    poetry run python update_pyproject_toml.py
    del update_pyproject_toml.py
    
    git init
    poetry run pre-commit install

    echo Done.
)
else (
    echo pyenv or specified Python version not installed.
)

exit /B
```

This script was working fine since my last use at the start of this week. Today, I attempted to use it again, but for some reason it's breaking now. Turning on `@echo on`, I can see that it runs

```
if [%2] NEQ [] (
    pyenv shell %2
)
```

and terminates there. There's no output, no error message. It just stops. Further debugging shows that `%ERRORLEVEL%` is 0 and the pyenv shell is correctly set, but somehow the rest of the code doesn't run when it used to. I haven't edited this script so I don't know what went wrong.

Please help?

Comment: I don't have `pyenv` installed, but I assume this is the usual thing where `pyenv` is a batch script and you need to use `call pyenv shell %2` so that flow returns to the main script after the subscript completes execution.

Comment: Your script has a very obvious issue. The carriage return/line feed character on line 38 should be replaced with a space character!

Comment: The `call` must be inserted before *any* executable that is a batch file, not a `.exe`. Your `else` syntax is incorrect. Where an 'else' clause is used, the ending parenthesis of the "true" block, a space and the `else` keyword must be on the same physical line. Where an 'else' block is used, the `else` keyword, a separator and the opening parenthesis of the "else" block must be on the same physical line